# Why would flares be fired into the air after a flight lands?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, airport

On Monday 23rd September at about 14:30 BST my plane landed at London Stansted. Soon after landing, while the plane was at the end of its deceleration, I noticed what appeared to be two flares or fireworks shot about 50 ft into the air above the grass to the right of the runway (I believe it was runway 22).

What on Earth could that be about? The flight was Ryanair FR587 (and the plane's registration was EI-DYL if anyone is interested).

Comment: One possibility is [scaring away birds](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11760/62), although I have no idea if it's possible to confirm that or not.

Comment: [Bird-scaring flares at Birmingham Airport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBlxpIgI9IY)

Comment: @user52723a That is what it looked like (although I couldn't see where they were being fired from)

Comment: Checked your flight at FlightRadar24. There was no such flight as FR587, but there was a flight EI-DYL. It was FR4030. Could that be you're aircraft?

Comment: @FallenUser It was FR587

Comment: Unfortunately, FlightRadar24 cannot replay any of the flights of the aircraft or even find the flight.

Comment: @FallenUser I don't think it will help to answer the question, anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the ways to keep the birds away from airfields?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/what-are-the-ways-to-keep-the-birds-away-from-airfields)

Answer (score 5):

I know that flares are used at Dover air force base in Delaware sometimes to deter birds from the airfield. I also know that flares are just a common bird deterrent anyway. So it may have been simply to clear the taxiways and runways of birds before the next departure or arrival.