# What was this mystery flash on an airport runway?

Tags: airport, airport-operations, airport-lighting

Recently I was onboard a commercial airliner and we had just landed and were headed for the gate. I cannot remember exactly which airport but it was either Schiphol(Amsterdam Airport) or Bristol. As we were taxiing I was looking out of the window and saw an object(?) fall vertically into my eyeline from about 10 m up. This object was maybe 50 m away and was at the edge of an intersecting adjacent runway/road and the grass. I noticed it because it had a faint trail of smoke emanating from it. At around 3 m above the ground it ignited, there was a short white flash and it made a small white cloud of smoke that lingered for a short while.

Does anyone know what this might have been? It was almost like a flare/firework (which makes no sense at an airport) so is there another explanation?

Comment: This seems to be a dupe of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45325/62), although arguably this one has better answers right now.

Comment: "At around 3 m from the **floor** it ignited".  Or the ground?

Comment: Bird / Passenger scarer. :-)

Comment: @RonJohn The ground

Comment: @Dannie Can't vouch for the birds but can confirm it was a passenger scarer

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's likely to be a flare / flash bang for bird control. Schiphol uses these (amongst a wide variety of methods).

> **Bird dispersal equipment**
>
> There are various resources a bird controller
>   can use to keep birds away from the runways. Standard equipment
>   includes a flare gun with noise blanks, a bird alarm call system and a
>   green laser.
>
> The flares and noise blanks come in various types,
>   including a number of ‘whizzers’. The flare used depends on the bird
>   species and the number of birds the controller wants to scare away.
>   Some species respond better to a loud bang and others to a screeching
>   noise. Bird controllers also have all the most common bird alarm calls
>   at their disposal, which act as a warning for the other members of the
>   species to leave the area as soon as possible. All bird controller
>   vehicles are equipped with a mobile green laser. This is a type of
>   torch that emits a green laser beam to chase water birds away from the
>   surrounding ditches.

Source: [Schiphol Bird Control information brochure](http://www.schiphol.nl/en/download/b2b/1524742453/6eMg60eBX2Ges0MkkuUiK0.pdf)

At Schiphol the Bird Control vehicles are equipped with ADS-B. This makes them visible on flightradar24. If you remember the day of your flight, you maybe able to see if they were operating in the area near your taxiing aircraft. The cars have callsign Kievit (peewit / lapwing) and use abbreviation "KV#" as flight ID on ADS-B.

Comment: Trivia: they're probably called Kievit because their primary purpose in the 70's was moving the native kieviten from the landing strips to safer areas. They have radar on board and equipment to produce the angry sounds from up to 42 types of bird.

Comment: @Mast So they literally make angry birds sounds?

Comment: @Michael Technically the sounds are the equivalent of what birds of those species would make to warn for danger, sending the birds away. But, yes.

Answer (score 25):

Likely a flash-bang for runway bird control.

Birds on and near the runway are an ongoing major safety problem (witness the "Miracle on the Hudson", an A320 brought down by a flock of geese shutting down both engines).  Measures to convince them to go elsewhere are only ever temporary and of limited effectiveness.

One of the measures that is commonly used is launching what amount to large firecrackers out of air cannon.  The launchers have enough range to be placed out of the way of aircraft traffic, but can reach the whole field (and the aim doesn't need to be terribly precise, they won't be fire when there are actually aicraft in the target area).

Comment: Thanks, @Bianfable.  Corrected.

Comment: From what I can remember seeing, this explanation seems perfectly plausible!

Comment: @NathanThomas Also see DeltaLima's answer, it's specific to Schipol.